# Get element value of json in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

See below my json array

```
[{'message_id':'1'}{'message_id':'2'}]
```

How to get `message_id` in jQuery Please Help me.

Comment: Read the documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value)

Comment: You are missing a comma in between your array items btw.

Comment: This is not a valid `json array`! There's no comma between the items

Answer (score 0):

Just loop the json array like this

```
var jsondata = [{'message_id':'1'},{'message_id':'2'}];
for(i=0; i<jsondata.length;i++) {
   console.log(jsondata[i].message_id);
}
```

Comment: @PalashMondal There was an error in my code can you copy paste updated solution and check once?

Comment: Here's the [**solution**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value#answer-11922384) with full explanation...

Comment: So what do u want to say is this answer is not correct or what?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use indexer, you are also missing comma between two objects.

```
yourobjArr = $.parseJSON("[{'message_id':'1'}, {'message_id':'2'}]");
yourobjArr[0].message_id
```

To iterate through all array elements

```
for(i=0; i< yourobjArr.length;i++) 
{
    message_id =  yourobjArr[i].message_id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this:

```
var arr = [{'message_id':'1'}, {'message_id':'2'}];
var ids = [];
arr.map(function (item) {
   ids.push(item["message_id"]);
});
console.log(ids); //all ids will be stored here.
```

**OR**

```
var arr = [{'message_id':'1'}, {'message_id':'2'}];
var firstId = arr[0]["message_id"]; //access the particular id
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: Just copied OP's array declaration, thought it's valid. Edited.

Comment: What about the second one, after OR ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
arr = [{'message_id':'1a'},{'message_id':'2a'}];
for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
    alert(arr[j]['message_id']);
}
```

<kbd>[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/arulmr/3b2Qg/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
var json_arr = [{'message_id':'1'},{'message_id':'2'}];
for(var i = 0; i < json_arr.length; i++){
  alert(json_arr[i].message_id);
}
```